# Are there multiple UTF-8 characters 'å' and how do I then compare them?

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm importing a dataset and need to read the filenames which contain some information. However, when I compare the string that is printed with itself it returns `True` if I copy the printed string, but `False` if I type it on my keyboard.

```py
    from os import walk

    path = "./dataset"
    _, _, file_names = next(walk(path))
    print(file_names)
    print(file_names[2]) # This prints "Gå(3).zip"

    print(file_names[2] == "Gå(3).zip")
```

I've narrowed down that this is due to the character 'å'. I'm using python 3.7.0, UTF-8 in my editor and running on macOS Big Sur. My question is whether there are identical UTF-8 characters with non-identical encoding? And how do I then compare them?

I've looked around stackoverflow for similar questions but the results drown in problems with python 2.x.

Comment: Look up diacritical marks in unicode set. `"a\u030a"` and `"\u00e5"` both display as this `å`, but the first combines two characters. Checking the length of a string may already give a hint that this is happening.

Comment: As you see, there are many different type of similar/same character. 1- canonical equivalent (usually one single character vs. character + combining character like accent). Programs should treat both in a equivalent manner (but for size and codepoint printing). 2- compatibility character: for compatibility with legacy encoding, it is sometime good to have different characters (like greek letter mu, and mu in units, Amstrong unit or A with the circle). 3- alphabets have complete set, but sometime characters are the same A (latin, greek, cyrillic) with different codes. Use OS functions

Comment: Thank you for the answers, solved the problem and understand the issue now!